# Does the PostgreSQL COPY command have the option of choosing which fields to map the CSV columns to?

Tags: postgresql, copy, csv

Does the PostgreSQL `COPY` command have the option of choosing which fields to map the CSV columns to?

The PostgreSQL `COPY` command appears to expect that the target table matches its columns exactly. Am I missing something or is that how it actually works?

Is there some alternative command that enables that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is absolutely possible - the ever helpful [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) comes to the rescue, again:

```
COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
    FROM { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDIN }
    [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
```

Which means you can do something like this:

```
COPY my_table (mt_id, mt_name, mt_created_by, ...)
    FROM 'filename' [...]
```

What you cannot do is to refer columns of the CSV file.  To overcome this, one can create an intermediate table with the matching number and type of columns, do the `COPY` into it, then do an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` to the final destination.  Based on an important remark from [Patrick7](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/88126/patrick7), the intermediate table can be defined as [`UNLOGGED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtable.html#AEN78527), saving a lot of WAL overhead when the table is big.

Comment: Little hint for the "intermediate table" you can use an UNLOGGED Table, to reduce WAL's and import time.

Answer (score 4):

Grab yourself a copy of [CSVKit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/540/)

```
in2csv foo.csv 
  | csvcut -C "columnIDontWant,AnotherIDontWant" 
  | csvsql --db postgresql://localhost/dbname --insert --tables Foo --no-create
```

Or [csvquote](https://github.com/dbro/csvquote)

```
csvquote | cut -d, -f... | csvquote - u | psql ...
```